# HTML to PDF page does not converting properly with A4 page size

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, wkhtmltopdf

I'm new b rails, I have successfully produced PDF from the HTML with wkhtmltopdf[0.11.0 rc1] free version, using ruby on rails(3.1).

I want that PDF in A4 printable size. (PDF have multiple pages.)

but it seems generated PDF having small size 
my HTML wrapper/main `DIV` having  `width: 580px;` and wrapper `DIV` is centered By `margin: auto;` 

I'm already using Wicked-PDF and facing this issue in the generated PDF. using page_size as A4.

```
pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(render_to_string(
             template: 'assessment_reports/assessment_report.html.haml', 
             layout: "layouts/reports.html.haml", 
             handlers: [ :haml ], margin: { :left => "5mm",:right => "5mm", :top => "20mm", :bottom => "0mm" },
             locals: { :@view_mode => "pdf" }
          ))
```

**Que is-** how do i convert/scale its width- 210mm(which is width of A4 paper) and height proportionally while generating pdf? *Not require but if possible-resolution should 300DPI.*

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can use wicked_pdf gem. You can specify :page_size => 'A4' to get A4 printable size. Link to github repo https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf

Comment: @Dipak- answer updated ..please look at it

Comment: The generated pdf is of size A4 but you are getting small sized pdf because your HTML wrapper/main width is 580 px.

Since you are using a separate layout for pdf. You can add a new css file specific for pdf inwhich don't specify the width for wrapper. It will take A4 size width automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and this argument to wkhtmltopdf solved the issue for me:

```
--disable-smart-shrinking
```